# How to clear a specific line with NCurses?

Tags: c, ncurses

How to clear a specific line with NCurses?

I need to wipe a line on the screen without redrawing the whole thing. *How do I do that?*

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can position on the line you want to clear and then call [`clrtoeol`](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/curs_clear.3.asp) function.

Answer (score 22):

This is how I ended up doing it for my purposes.

```
int y, x;            // to store where you are
getyx(stdscr, y, x); // save current pos
move(y, 0);          // move to begining of line
clrtoeol();          // clear line
move(y, x);          // move back to where you were
```

Comment: any chance you know how to do this in vertical scope? meaning clear all lines until last line

Answer (score 3):

maybe [crltoeol](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcurses/clrtoeol.html) would do the trick

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear all lines from the cursor until the last line, you can call `clrtobot()`