# c++ Print on same line

Tags: c++, printing, cout

I am using a chrono to get the time elapsed during a loop. I would like to display this time every loop run.

I can do this:

```
for(int i = 0;i<3;i++)
{
    sleep(2 secs);
    time= get_time();
    cout<<"time is : "<<time;
}
```

But I have the output:

```
time is : 2 time is : 4 time is : 6
```

I could add an `endl` to have it in column but that is not what I want. My loop is about million times, so I don't really want to print a million lines.

I would just like to print like:

```
time is : 2
```

and then refresh it to

```
time is : 4
```

and so on.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Experiment with the carriage-return `'\r'` character.

Comment: Working with \r and flush ! thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use endl with clrscr() .

Comment: thanks but i didnt want to erase my previous output on the console before this loop

Comment: This is not a portable solution. OP did not specify a compiler or platform.

Answer (score 1):

printing to terminals is very easy, but it can be extremely hard at the same time. At its core, a terminal is simply a file, that you can use to write or read on. Performing tasks such as changing cursor's position is in fact system-specific and your code will have to be platform dependent.

But don't panic! People have done it before and even wrote libraries to do it. I think NCurses will do the job. https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html

I advice you to refer to this thread to see some issue related to your question: [How to clear a specific line with NCurses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072881/how-to-clear-a-specific-line-with-ncurses)

I have never used ncurses my self, so I wish you best of luck!

Enjoy programming!