# low level printing in C

Tags: c, printing, low-level

I know how to print string or chars in C, but i'm wondering how i could modify a string that have already been printed in the screen (like when you install some packages and # fills the |####---->| 50%), without using any other functions than syscalls.

Comment: "printing" on printer or on screen?

Comment: on screen (in shell).

Comment: You cannot move the "cursor" once the data is sent to stdout using standard C, without using some API calls or knowing the specifics of your console. However, progress bar can be rendered using the carriage return (`\r`) character.

Comment: also : [Erase the current printed console line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508490/erase-the-current-printed-console-line)

Comment: On unix you would want to use a specialized library like curses/ncurses which manages the terminal capabilities for you thru all the termcap database knowledge. On other systems, other libraries...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the carriage return:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%s", "Hello, ");
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
    printf("\r%s\n", "World!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `Hello, ` string is never shown that way

Comment: I modified it to add `fflush(stdout)`. It also sleeps before it shows `World!`.

Comment: Nice! I did not know you could do that :)

Comment: This is the first time I know about `fflush`, thank you.