# How to remove the last line in xterm.js

Tags: xtermjs

I'm trying to remove the last line of a xtermjs terminal. In the docs I have only found the `clear` and `reset` methods, but I just want to remove the last line.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solved this based on the answers of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508490/erase-the-current-printed-console-line)

> \33[2K erases the entire line your cursor is currently on
>
> \033[A moves your cursor up one line, but in the same column i.e. not
>   to the start of the line
>
> \r brings your cursor to the beginning of the line (r is for rewind)
>   but does not erase anything

I ended up using this to erase the last line:

```
terminal.write('\x1b[2K\r')
```

\x1b is the hexadecimal of \033, because I was getting this error when using the octal version.

> Octal literal in strict mode