# How to make countdown timer print result on single line in C?

Tags: c, printing, printf

I have code here which works as a countdown timer but it prints results on a new line
like this:

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

here is my code:

```
int timer()
{
        int count;
        count = 10;

        while(count != 0)
        {
                printf("Time: \t%d \n", count);
                count--;
                sleep(1);
        }

        printf("\nCount down timer has expired\n");
        return 0;
}
```

what I've tried so far is to change \n to \r to print on a single line but it did not work. I'm trying to make it clear the line and print the next number in the line then clear that and print the next one if that makes sense

Comment: Try flushing the buffer after each print `printf("Time: \t%d ", count); fflush(stdout);`.  Does that work for you?

Comment: sort of. it printed like this: Time:   5Time:  4Time:  3Time:  2Time:  1

Comment: If it prints like that then you missed the space. And if you expect it to print just the number then skip the Time string

Comment: @Martheen which space?

Comment: @mikejosnton The only other space in that string (following `%d`). Regardless console-cursor positioning quickly falls into toolkit land, usually something like ncurses.

Comment: Now its printing like this:  5       4       3       2       1
Count down timer has expired

Comment: @Martheen do you know how I can get it to clear the line and print the next number in the line then clear that and print the next one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Erase the current printed console line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508490/erase-the-current-printed-console-line)

Comment: Carriage return statement worked for my compiler. I'm getting (Time: 10) *clear* (Time: 9) *clear* (Time: 8) ... Just for clarification, are you using Linux systems or Windows?

Comment: Try with `printf("\rTime: \t%d ", count);` followed by `fflush(stdout);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `fflush(stdout)` after using `\r` in your `printf` as mentioned by pmg:

```c
int timer()
{
        int count;
        count = 10;

        while(count != 0)
        {
                printf("Time: \t%d \r", count);
                fflush(stdout);
                count--;
                sleep(1);
        }

        printf("\nCount down timer has expired\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `printf("Time: \t%d \n", count);` to `printf("Time: \t%d \t", count);`

Answer (score 0):

Use `"\b \b"` to clear one character. Imagine you just printed "42": the 1st `'\b'` moves the cursor back to over the 2, then the space 'clears' that 2, and finally go back again one more space.

```
    printf("Time: \t");
    while(count != 0)
    {
            printf("%d", count);
            fflush(stdout);
            sleep(1);
            if (count >= 100) printf("\b \b");
            if (count >= 10) printf("\b \b");
            if (count >= 1) printf("\b \b");
            count--;
    }
    printf(" \n");
```