# C# clear Console last Item and replace new? Console Animation

Tags: c#, console.writeline

The following CSharp Code(just sample):

```
Console.WriteLine("Searching file in...");

foreach(var dir in DirList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dir);
}
```

Prints Output As:

```
Searching file in...

dir1

dir2

dir3

dir4

.

.

.
```

**Question?**
How can I get the output as

```
Searching file in...

dir1
```

> (then clear dir1 and print dir2 and so on)All next dir name wiil replace the previous dir

Comment: The problem is same like[1], there are some ways to solve it.
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888533/how-can-i-update-the-current-line-in-a-c-sharp-windows-console-app/11322943#11322943

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If your problem is clearing the console then use the method `Console.Clear();`, if it's not, use this to overwrite the last line;

```
Console.WriteLine("Searching file in...");
        foreach(var dir in DirList)
         {
           Console.SetCursorPosition(1,0);
           Console.WriteLine(dir);
         }
```

Comment: I don't want to clear all Console. Just last one printed line

Answer (score 33):

Use [`Console.SetCursorPosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition.aspx) to set the cursor on the start of the last line and rewrite it.

Something like:

```
Console.WriteLine(dir);
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
```

---

**EDIT:**

According to your comment, you could do as follows:

```
Console.WriteLine("Searching file in...");
foreach (var dir in DirList)
{
    ClearCurrentConsoleLine();
    Console.Write(dir);
}
```

With `ClearCurrentConsoleLine` defined as:

```
public static void ClearCurrentConsoleLine()
{
    int currentLineCursor = Console.CursorTop;
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
    for (int i = 0; i < Console.WindowWidth; i++)
        Console.Write(" ");
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, currentLineCursor);
}
```

Comment: If i set the start position (as start of current printed line)then I need to clear. But it will clear all screen

Comment: Your code is working fine for this code. But in my actuall code I am triggering a event foreach dir name and that passes the current dir name to event handler and that event handler prints the current Item. I am using consolewriteline in eventHandler. I tried same code but its not functioning

Comment: @GAPS: Probably you just need to call `ClearCurrentConsoleLine` and `Write` (not `WriteLine`) in the eventhandler, but I can't be sure because I don't know exaclty your code.  
Anyway I think you can easily adjust the code to fit your needs, you just need to figure out how it works and, I assure, that's really simple.

Comment: @digEmAii  thanx, it is helpful but I need to customize it according to my code

Comment: I think using `Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth - 1))`  might be a bit faster than the loop

Comment: @Ray: yes probably, even if I doubt you can notice the difference :)

Answer (score 12):

You could print using "\r", that way cursor dont jump a line, and you can rewrite it.

```
foreach(var dir in DirList)
     {
       Console.Write("\r{0}%           ",dir);
     }
```

use spaces after number to make sure everything is erased, and use .Write instead of WriteLine
because you dont want to add "\n"

Comment: This fails if the initial WriteLine wrapped around.

Answer (score 6):

Just keep track of the current position of the cursor by saving the values of the `Console.CursorLeft` and `Console.CursorTop` properties.  Then write, reset and repeat.  Or rather in this case, reset, write and repeat.

```
Console.WriteLine("Searching file in...");

// save the current cursor position
var cursorLeft = Console.CursorLeft;
var cursorTop = Console.CursorTop;

// build a format string to establish the maximum width do display
var maxWidth = 60;
var fmt = String.Format("{{0,-{0}}}", maxWidth);

foreach (var dir in dirList)
{
    // restore the cursor position
    Console.SetCursorPosition(cursorLeft, cursorTop);

    // trim the name if necessary
    var name = Path.GetFileName(dir);
    if (name.Length > maxWidth)
        name = name.Substring(0, maxWidth);

    // write the trimmed name
    Console.Write(fmt, name);

    // do some work
}
Console.WriteLine(); // end the previous line
```

Comment: hmm.. that looks charming. Let me try it

Answer (score 3):

Although this is a quite old post, I will post my approach. Maybe this would help someone

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
Console.Write(new String(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
Console.Write(dir);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want ;)

```
Console.WriteLine("Searching file in...");
    foreach(var dir in DirList)
     {
       Console.Write(\"r" + dir);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do what I *think* you're asking for:

```
string s = "\r";
s += new string(' ', Console.CursorLeft);
s += "\r";
Console.Write(s);
```

Essentially the same as @digEmAll suggested, but it uses the actual # of chars instead of Console.WindowWidth