# c# console application dot effect

Tags: c#, string, console

I wish to add a "..." effect after the end of one of my strings in a console application I'm building. For example,

```
Hello World. > Hello World.. > Hello World...
```

The problem is, how can I do this so that the dots are not shown straight away? But in more a sequential fashion, ie one after another, maybe a new dot is shown every half second or so.

Any help/advice/guidance is greatly appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888533/how-can-i-update-the-current-line-in-a-c-sharp-windows-console-app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Thread.Sleep(milliseconds) in between the Console.Write(".") statements.

```
for(int i = 0;i < 5;i++)
{
  Console.Write(".");
  Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
        for (int dots = 0; dots <= 3; ++dots)
        {
            Console.Write("\rHello world{0}", new string('.', dots));
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500); // half a sec
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nAll done.");
```

Comment: Anyone know how I would do this in a message box