# Set Console Cursor to Thick/Thin

Tags: c#, console, cursor, console-application

In command prompt, when you press the insert button, the cursor changes from a thin bar to a thicker bar to show that it is in overwrite mode, and when you press it again, it makes it thin again to show that it is in insert mode
is there any way to do this in C#?

EDIT:
I want to know if there's a way to make the cursor thick/thin, not how to overwrite text

Comment: Are you intending to overwrite characters and/or stay on the same line when using Console.Write?  If so, there are several ways.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888533/how-can-i-update-the-current-line-in-a-c-sharp-windows-console-app  But is that what you want?  Maybe a clearer explanation of what you're trying to do.

Comment: i'm trying to be able to make the cursor either thick or thin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Console.CursorSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cursorsize%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property to change the "thickness" of the cursor.

The above respective MSDN page gives all the information you need, plus an example. Just note one thing though: if you change the cursor size in your application and then exit, it remains at that size, unless you change it explicitly back (or use the `CMD` window`s properties to do so).

Example (rudimentary to illustrate the point):

```
public static void Main()
{
    int originalSize = Console.CursorSize;

    try
    {
       Console.CursorSize = 100; // Use "full" cursor
       ...  
    }
    finally 
    {
       // make sure we leave the cursor size as we found it.
       Console.CursorSize = originalSize;
    }
}
```

Finally, another word of warning: If you redirect the output of your application to a file or a pipe (`>` or `|`), the `Console.CursorSize` property will raise an `IOException`. Keep that in mind when thinking about how your application will be used.

Comment: Note however that using Console.CursorSize appears to reset the cursor shape, i.e. it forces the cursor to be a horizontal bar (or a horizontal block at 100% size). I am not aware of any way to _programatically_ change the cursor to (for example) a thin vertical bar, and even if you do this via the console properties, the cursor will be reset to a horizontal bar/block as soon as you use Console.CursorVisible.