# Countdown timer in console Application

Tags: c#, timer, console-application

I have a console application and I want to create a countdown timer. This is what I have tried:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int a = 10; a >= 0; a--)
        {
            Console.Write("Generating Preview in {0}", a);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.Clear();
        }
    }
```

This code works in some situations. However, the problem is that it clears the entire console window and cannot be used when there are some characters above the timer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/888569/1693085 - Rather than `Console.Clear()`, use `\r` in your actual line of text...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two ways i know of doing what you want

1) Use `Console.SetCursorPosition();`. This is applicable when you are sure of the amount of characters that will be above the timer.

2) Use `Console.CursorLeft`. This is applicable in all cases.

#### Code Examples

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   for (int a = 10; a >= 0; a--)
   {
      Console.SetCursorPosition(0,2);
      Console.Write("Generating Preview in {0} ", a);  // Override complete previous contents
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
   }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Console.Write("Generating Preview in ");
   for (int a = 10; a >= 0; a--)
   {
      Console.CursorLeft = 22;
      Console.Write("{0} ", a );    // Add space to make sure to override previous contents
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
   }
}
```

Comment: You could also use `Console.Write( "Generating Preview in {0:00}", a );` to **always display the timer value with a two-digit number**. This way you don't need to add a space at the end to make sure you overwrite the previous two-digit number completely.

Answer (score 17):

If you print  `"\r"` to the console the cursor goes back to the beginning of the current line, so this works:

```
for (int a = 10; a >= 0; a--)
{
    Console.Write("\rGenerating Preview in {0:00}", a);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: Great answer, but there is a tiny bug. The timer will display 10, 90, 80, 70,... Pad a space at the end of the string and everything will display fine.

Answer (score 2):

[Console.SetCursorPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition.aspx)  and related is what you probably looking for. Get current position and set it again back aster every `Write`/`WriteLine` call.

Something like:

```
var origRow = Console.CursorTop;
for (int a = 10; a >= 0; a--)
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, origRow);
    Console.Write("Generating Preview in {0}", a);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, origRow);
Console.Write("Generating Preview done.....");
```

Comment: This still clears whatever text is above the timer

Comment: @TijesunimiPreciousAmesinlola Just remove .Clear call... copy/paste error

Answer (score 2):

One easy trick you can use is to place a `\r` in your string to return it the cursor to the beginning of the current line:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("This text stays here");
    for (int a = 10; a >= 0; a--)
    {
        Console.Write("\rGenerating Preview in {0}", a);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```