# How to make a Stopwatch without rewrite line for each display

Tags: c#, .net, console, stopwatch

I want to display a stopwatch but i don't want to clean my console for each dislay ,

```
            Stopwatch chrono = new Stopwatch();
            chrono.Start();

            bool isMyComputerOn = true;
            while (isMyComputerOn)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Time :  "+chrono.Elapsed);
            }
```

Any idea ?

Comment: not exactly but it help me, thank you for solving my problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use SetCursorPosition to fix the position of you cursor

```
Stopwatch chrono = new Stopwatch();
chrono.Start();
bool isMyComputerOn = true;
while (isMyComputerOn)
{
   Console.SetCursorPosition(1,1);
   Console.WriteLine("Time : "+chrono.Elapsed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve what you want with something like

```
Console.Write("Time :  "+chrono.Elapsed+"           \r");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the `Console.CursorLeft` and `Console.CursorTop` properties to local integer variables. Then before calling `Console.WriteLine()` set the cursor position in the console by using `Console.SetCursorPosition()`.

Example:

```
        Stopwatch chrono = new Stopwatch();
        chrono.Start();

        bool isMyComputerOn = true;
        int cursorCol = Console.CursorLeft;
        int cursorRow = Console.CursorTop;
        while (isMyComputerOn)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(cursorCol, cursorRow);
            Console.WriteLine("Time :  " + chrono.Elapsed);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer to an similar question:

```
for(int i = 60; i >= 0; i--)
{
Console.Write("\r{0}%   ", i);
}
```

[How can I update the current line in a C# Windows Console App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888533/how-can-i-update-the-current-line-in-a-c-sharp-windows-console-app)