# Interesting OOPS puzzle

Tags: c#, oop, puzzle

Recently, I faced the below question in an interview. Initially I thought that the question was wrong, but the interviewer mentioned there is a solution for this. Given this class:

```
public class BaseHome
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
}
```

Write the following to the console:

```
B
A
C
```

Rules:

1. Do not change the Main function.
2. Do not create any additional classes.

How can this be done?

Comment: @user2864740 Not allowed to create addition classes

Comment: Did you mean `Main` instead of `main`?

Comment: @ken2k I saw that too. So the solution could be to just create a Main method

Comment: not allowed to type anything on the keyboard or move the mouse

Comment: As this is not a program, I assume B and C are ouput from the program which call BaseHome.main to supply the A

Comment: Could this possibly be just a catch question with a syntax "error" in it? What a cruel interviewer!

Comment: To make question more clear - you are allowed only to call `BaseHome.main()` and this should print B A C?

Comment: If it is about a syntax error, this question is eligible to get closed as *"off topic, caused by problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error"*

Comment: How about BaseHome extends Console and then override WriteLine? Is that allowed?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: Isn't that an invalid edit? Maybe the Op deliberately put that sequence on one line? After all its a console app.

Comment: @abhitalks: it was on three lines in the source but due to the formatting interpretation it was put on one line. All Sergey did was put the indentation before each line.

Comment: @abhitalks that's a valid edit. OP had three lines

Comment: This is really a question for CodeGolf.SE.

Comment: Agreed, this question is a much better fit for [CodeGolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 49):

Assuming you meant B A C on three lines (plus no typo on `main` method name):

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class BaseHome
    {
        static BaseHome()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B");

            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(OnProcessExit);
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A");
        }

        private static void OnProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("C");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, I think that is solution. I was thinking about timer, but this is better solution

Comment: +1 Well done. This works as required.

Comment: +1 Amazing. I couldn't even think of ProcessExit!

Comment: What is this static BaseHome()-method? Is this a constructor?

Comment: @bodycountPP Ref. [Static Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx): "A static constructor is used to initialize any static data, or to perform a particular action that needs to be performed once only. It is called automatically before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced."

Answer (score 25):

Hahaha, I figured it out. Create a static property!

```
public class BaseHome
{
    public static void Main()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("A");
    }

    public static BaseHome Console
    {
        get{ return new BaseHome(); }
    }

    public void WriteLine(string s) {
        System.Console.WriteLine("BCA"); //Or multiple lines if you like
    }

}
```

Edit: Or, duh, just a field

```
public class BaseHome
{
    static BaseHome Console = new BaseHome();

    public static void Main()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("A");
    }

    public void WriteLine(string s) {
        System.Console.WriteLine("BCA"); //Or multiple lines if you like
    }

}
```

Comment: That's pretty neat imo.

Comment: Clever answer. I like this because it indicates that you pay attention to details. The `BaseHome` console program/class could _easily_ be `static` (and, at least in my experience, it usually is static, or at least not treated like an instantiable class). This takes advantage of that detail and wouldn't work otherwise.

Comment: If the class were static, you can make a property that returns an anonymous type, but I don't know if that violates the do-not-create-a-class constraint:     public static dynamic Console {
        get {
            Action<string> WriteLine = s => System.Console.WriteLine("BCA");
         return new { WriteLine };
        }
    }

Comment: @Dennis_E: Good thinking. If anonymous types aren't allowed (which seems quite plausible) you can use an [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) instead!

Comment: This is why C# is my favorite language; so many beautiful features!

Comment: Wow, that's a good one!

Answer (score 17):

No new types. No objects explicitly created. Works in a real Console application.

```
public class BaseHome
{
    static System.IO.TextWriter Console
    {
        get
        {
            System.Console.Write("  C\rB");
            return System.Console.Out;
        }
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
        // System.Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Result is `BAC` - on the same line no less!

(This can be adapted to multiple line output, per the post edit, with the use of [CurstorLeft/Top](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cursorleft(v=vs.110).aspx) or direct escape sequences.)

---

Explanation:

The static property (`Console`) is resolved instead of the type in `Console.WriteLine("A")` as the property *shadows* the type here; this is why System.Console is used to refer to the Console class itself.

The Console get-property causes a side-effect of writing to the console - it writes "__C" then uses CR (Carriage Return) to "return to the line start" and writes "B" so the line is "B_C", leaving the cursor after the "B".

The property then returns the [TextWriter associated with the console](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.out(v=vs.110).aspx) which has WriteLine. The [TextWriter's WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.writeline.aspx), not Console's static WriteLine, is then invoked and the character "A" is written (after "B") so the result is "BAC".

This utilizes context-specific behavior because it is the console which [understands how to move the cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888533/how-can-i-update-the-current-line-in-a-c-sharp-windows-console-app) (e.g. with "\r" or  other cursor positioning).

Comment: That's pretty clever!

Comment: That's quite sneaky. You could also just redirect the Console's output stream in a static constructor. See my answer.

Comment: Explanation, I demand one!

Comment: @bodycountPP Wish granted.

Answer (score 13):

Just a static constructor is needed:

```
public class BaseHome
{
    static BaseHome()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B\nA\nC");
        Console.SetOut(System.IO.TextWriter.Null);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
}
```

Instead of redirecting the output stream, other options include calling `Environment.Exit`, throwing an unhandled exception, or just spinning forever. It is unclear if the program is required to terminate normally (or at all).

Comment: Clever to simply "disconnect" the output.

Answer (score 5):

```
struct ConsoleStruct
{
    private string _text;
    public ConsoleStruct(string text)
    {
        _text = text;
    }

    public void WriteLine(string txt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_text);
    }
}
class Program
{
    private static ConsoleStruct Console = new ConsoleStruct("B A C");
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
}
```

Comment: Easy to fix by just making WriteLine in the struct take an argument that it ignores.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen yeah, fixed it. Still a much worse solution than ken2k's

Comment: Should not create any additional class implied no structs too imho in this context