# how to use reflection to change non existing field in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have below code block and it should print 404 without using unsafe code or any changes to the Mutate method

```
const string constStr = "000";
Mutate(constStr);
var nonConst = "000";
Console.WriteLine(nonConst);  

static void Mutate(string str)
{
    
}
```

Comment: You are asking for magic?

Comment: I guess so :). I was asked to find an answer and I guess there is one but couldn't find as of now

Comment: There are several different ways to achieve that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078082/interesting-oops-puzzle for some ideas.

Comment: Presumably we might have ideas if you show a more fitting sample. This one is just "useless". constStr and nonConst are two different strings they have nothing in coming  besides conrtaining the same value coincidently. So Mutate does not do anything here and can be ignored just like the first two line in your code. So whats left is defining a variable and outputting it on the console. To get what you want simply change the variable in between these two lines. Thats not a problem so its presumably not what you want to ask or want to know.

Comment: @NineBerry any recommendations on how I can use it to solve my case?

Comment: Please provide the specific requirements. Your title mentions reflection and invisible fields but that seems unrelated. Also provide the full program source if available.

Comment: Is it allowed to add code inside the Mutate method without changing its signature?

Comment: I provided full code. Firstly I thought I had to use reflection but ProcessExit seems like it might work @NineBerry

Comment: @NineBerry yes, you can add code to Mutate method

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on NineBerry's comment and Matthew's answer, I have found a workaround. As long as a class with the same structure as a string is constructed, all chars of the string will be mapped to the corresponding fields of that class.

```
const string constStr = "000";
var nonConst = "000";
Mutate(constStr);
Console.WriteLine(nonConst);

static void Mutate(string s)
{
    var nasty = new StringToChar { str = s };
    var mock = nasty.chr!;
    mock.first = '4';
    mock.third = '4';
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct StringToChar
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public MockString chr;
    [FieldOffset(0)] public string str;
}

public class MockString
{
    public int Length;
    public char first, _, third;
}
```

Comment: nice. I want also ask one more thing. How I can modify const string? is there any hidden trick

Comment: @shingo That's false. String literals exist in mutable memory. There are tricks that can be used to change them. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37253663/101087 for an example. However these tricks will change working when internals of the runtime change. For example, the linked trick only works in .net Framework, not in .NET 5 or higher

Comment: @NineBerry Actually that does work in .NET 8, but it will only change one character of the `const` string.

Comment: @NineBerry, wow, this is amazing! And I tried .net8 and it actually works.

Comment: I looked at it again and the difference is actually between x86 and x64. It works on x86 but will only change one character on x64.

Answer (score 1):

This will output `"404"` when compiled as an x86 project. (NOTE: It will output "`004`" for an x64 or AnyCPU build):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Console1;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        const string constStr = "000";
        var nonConst = "000";
        Mutate(constStr);
        Console.WriteLine(nonConst);
    }

    static void Mutate(string s)
    {
        var nasty = new StringToChar { str = s };
        char[] ch = nasty.chr!;

        ch[0] = '4';
        ch[1] = '0';
        ch[2] = '4';
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct StringToChar
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public char[] chr;
    [FieldOffset(0)] public string str;
}
```

Yes, this is nasty. NEVER DO THIS!

(Based on [an old answer of mine here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37253663/106159).)