# Displaying progress in one line?

Tags: c

Is it possible to display progress on one line instead of having the for-loop printing out a bunch of lines for every action?

Like, for example. Instead of this:

```
Progress: 0%
Progress: 15%
Progress: 50%
Progress: 100%
```

It does all that in one line (while showing progress, of course):

```
Progress: 100%
```

Basically, I'm making a sockets program to transfer files from one socket to another socket. And it's taking the amount transferred divided by the file size multiplied by 100 to get its percentage.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/888569/1870760

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I update the current line in a C# Windows Console App?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888533/how-can-i-update-the-current-line-in-a-c-sharp-windows-console-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
printf ("\r progress =%d", progress)
```