# count lines from text file and count it in 1 line

Tags: c#, .net

So what I want to do its count lines from a text file and count them in 1 line on the console window. This is what I have now, it works but it writes lot of lines to the console and I want it to change the count on 1 line every second.

```
long lines = 0;
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("text.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
          count++;
          Console.Title = "Count: " + lines;
          Console.WriteLine(Console.Title);
    }
}
```

Comment: `r.ReadAllLines().Count()` should do the trick

Comment: not work to me..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `File.ReadAllLiness(<filePath>).Count()` to get count of lines in text file.

```
Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllLiness("text.txt").Count())
```

---

Your code is not working because you are printing `lines` variable which is assigned as `0` at the beginning, but not updated anywhere.

Either try my first solution or use `lines` variable instead of `count` in your existing program and print it out of while loop

```
long lines = 0;
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("text.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(++lines); //One line solution
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah k but i want its do " live " count in the Console.WriteLine

Comment: Count.. 8076
Count.. 8077
Count.. 8078
Count.. 8079
Count.. 8080
Count.. 8081
Count.. 8082
Count.. 8083

its what its write (write lot of lines in console.. https://i.imgur.com/bp4tqIz.png) ^

i want to do it every 1 line its count so its write but in 1 line

Comment: its pretty simple write `Console.WriteLine()` inside while loop, so that when `StreamReader` reads one line print it on Console. I would suggest you to read about `StreamReader` and also `File` operations in C#. It will really helpful for you

Comment: I can not find any other way to minimize above code to make it one liner.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at this topic:

[How can I update the current line in a C# Windows Console App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888533/how-can-i-update-the-current-line-in-a-c-sharp-windows-console-app)

It is possible to update the current line. All you need to add is a logic to only do it once per second.

Maybe something like this:

```cs
long lines = 0;
var lastSecond = DateTime.Now.Second;
using (var r = new StreamReader("text.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        lines++;
        Console.Title = "Count: " + lines;
        if(lastSecond != DateTime.Now.Second)
            Console.Write("\r{0}   ", Console.Title);
        lastSecond = DateTime.Now.Second;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(""); // Create new line at the end
}
```

There will be nicer ways to update once per second but the main problem seems to be how to update the current console output.