# clock output not increasing

Tags: c#, methods

I am trying to make a Clock that displays in 24 hour time, like 00:00:00.
I've created the `ReadTime` method in my clock class. In my `MainClass` I assumed that if I called the `ReadTime` method in a while loop, that it would increase. However the output just stays at 0:0:0.

```
public class Clock
{
    Counter _seconds;
    Counter _minutes;
    Counter _hours;

    public Clock()
    {
        _seconds = new Counter("Seconds");
        _minutes = new Counter("Minutes");
        _hours = new Counter("Hours");
    }


    public void Tick()
    {
        _seconds.Increment();
        if(_seconds.Count>=60)
        {
            _minutes.Increment();
            _seconds.Reset();
        }

        if(_minutes.Count >= 60)
        {
            _minutes.Reset();
            _hours.Increment();
        }

        if(_hours.Count >= 24)
        {
            Reset();

        }
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _hours.Reset();
        _minutes.Reset();
        _seconds.Reset();
    }

    public void ReadTime()
    {
        string ss = _seconds.Count.ToString();
        string mm = _minutes.Count.ToString();
        string hh = _hours.Count.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine("{0:00}:{0:00}:{0:00}", hh, mm, ss);
    }
}
```

This is my main method.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Clock ClockDemo = new Clock();
        while(true)
        {
            ClockDemo.Tick();
            ClockDemo.ReadTime();
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

    }
```

Comment: If you try debugging the `ReadTime()` method and inspecting the values, you'll probably see that they actually are incrementing and that the issue is with the formatting of your string

Comment: You may also want to share the code of the Counter class? I don't think that this is a .net framework class.

Comment: Do this https://stackoverflow.com/a/888569/1704458

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is you already formatted your string before you put it in your custom formatting.

```
    string ss = _seconds.Count.ToString(); // 0 becomes "0"
    string mm = _minutes.Count.ToString();
    string hh = _hours.Count.ToString();

    Console.WriteLine("{0:00}:{0:00}:{0:00}", hh, mm, ss);
```

**It is not going to pad zeros to a string, only to an int.** So instead, try the following:

```
    string ss = _seconds.Count.ToString("00"); // 0 becomes "00"
    string mm = _minutes.Count.ToString("00");
    string hh = _hours.Count.ToString("00");

    Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}:{2}", hh, mm, ss);
```

You can also skip putting them in temporary string variables:

```
    Console.WriteLine("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", _hours.Count, _minutes.Count, _seconds.Count);
```

Or use interpolated string:

```
    Console.WriteLine($"{_hours.Count:00}:{_minutes.Count:00}:{_seconds.Count:00}");
```