WPF C# debug console - error with “\r” [Microsoft Visual Studio 2022; .net 8]
I have this code;
private void UpdateProgressBar(int currentPosition, int total, int barLength)
{
    if (total <= 0) return;
    int progressPercentage = (int)((currentPosition / (double)total) * 100);
    int filledBarLength = (progressPercentage * barLength) / 100;
    string progressBar = new string('=', filledBarLength).PadRight(barLength);
    Debug.Write($"\rProgress: [{progressBar}] {progressPercentage}% ({currentPosition}/{total})");

    if (currentPosition == total)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("");
    }
}

It receives the current position, the total number of steps and how long the display should be. The code works quite well in itself, but a new line is created each time it is executed, even though the string contains "\r" and even though I use "Debug.Write" instead of "Debug.WriteLine". I want the old display to be overwritten.
I do not want to use a graphical element in this use case.
What I have tried:
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/888559 (Here the current position is set, but in the debug console there is no corresponding function, and there is no standard console in WPF: the program says so anyway)
Is this even possible in WPF?
Thank you very much.

Debug listeners aren't like Console.Write() - they don't handle carriage return the same way. As you've discovered, a carriage return causes a newline. Generally speaking, when you write something to a debug output you don't want a subsequent write to destroy it.
